# Anaconda navigator Windows - add environment on other drive

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I face the following issue.

Right now Anaconda is installed on C: drive on our server. Due to corporate policy I can't use C: drive to create my environments there so I need to create environment on different drive - namely F: drive. How do I do that through Navigator? When I hit 'create'  button it allows me to just specify the name of new environment which will still be placed on C: drive.

Moreover, I used conda create --prefix F:\MyEnvironment to create environment manually but I am not sure how to force the Navigator to recognize this environment now. Import environment function not helps too - it will import environment into C: drive again.